# Getting contacts from SalesForce - 403 forbidden error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm trying to build a functionality where user can export contacts from salesforce. I used REST API and the below api to get contacts from user account. I'm able to access contacts from my account but if I login as different user(account which is not used to create the API key) then I'm not able to use the below API, I'm getting 403 forbidden error, am I doing something wrong?

```
services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+name,email+from+Contact
```

I tried to search for document related to this but unfortunately I couldn't able to find one. Can somebody please help me on this?

Comment: How are you getting an API access token?

Comment: Spoke to salesforce customer care and seems the API is available only for enterprise or unlimited plan. The access token which I had was for the professional plan that is the reason it was not working.